# Autogenerating key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

My understanding is that when using objectify, you can generate a datastore key in one of two ways:

1. Specify a unique ID to an object, which will be used to generate the datastore key (unique ID assigned to data member with annotation @Id)
2. Don't specify unique ID, so a datastore key will be autogenerated (Annotation @Id on data member still exists, but nothing is assigned to it)

Using option 1, in order to load a specified entity we first obtained a key using Key.create(SomeEntity.class, uniqueID) where uniqueID would be unique.

If I decide to go with option 2, how do I load a desired entity if I had let the datastore autogenerate a key?

Answer (score 0):

With any other parameter?  If you create an object without deciding on the key, but provide (for instance) a city, a userName, an email, then you search by city, username, email. Once you have that, you have the object. From there you can get the object's key if you need it.

Comment: Ah that sounds like an idea. But what if the uniqueness of the parameters that I query by cannot be guaranteed?

Comment: I'd need a better understanding of your precise usecase, but I don't see a reason to have two exact same entities in your datastore

Answer (score 0):

If your entity @Id field is null and you save it synchronously with .now() then the @Id annotated field (assumed "id" in this example) will be set to an auto-allocated/generated value during the following call.

```
ofy().save().entity(someEntity).now();
Long myId = someEntity.getId();
```

Then someEntity.getId() would be a valid generated String/Long that you can use, note somewhere, provide to a user, return from an API etc so that later:

```
ofy().load().type(Entity.class).id(myId).now();
```

If you need to save the entity asynchronously (without .now()) then that's possible too, just use the allocateId function from [ObjectifyFactory](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/ObjectifyFactory.html#allocateId%28java.lang.Class%29) to set the id before saving to ensure a unique id - this is similar to your 1) but a safe way to generate the UniqueId that is assured to be unique.

Searching afterwards for the entry by querying a combination of fields should typically be avoided as depending on your data it may not match a single entry and you'd need to index those fields adding costs.

Comment: In order to use 
ofy().load().type(Entity.class).id(someEntity.getId()).now();
you would need the reference 'someEntity' (so that someEntity.getId() can be invoked). But isn't the whole point of the line ofy().load().type(Entity.class).id(someEntity.getId()).now() to actually obtain 'someEntity' (well at least that was what I wanted to do). If I did not have a reference to 'someEntity' (which is why I want to use ofy.load(), to actually load 'someEntity' from datastore), it would seem impossible to retrieve it via key/id. Do you see where Im coming from? What am I missing?

Comment: It was a contrived example to just show that after save @id is populated and can be used to load the entity.  You don't need someEntity only its id (a string/long value).